# If Contains Statement for a new variable SQL

Tags: mysql, domo

Need help correcting my code for an if statement to create a new variable.

This is for help cleaning a data set for a project for my business. I want to search a column for multiple values and if that column contains any of those values it will add that value to another column. It has been a while since I learned sql in school and need some help with my code.

I am currently using Domo/MySQL tool to write the code. Essentially I want to find an advertisers name inside a url and return that advertiser into a new column and add this to the data set.

I have tried a few things, and I'm not sure what to use.

```
Select `Page`
from `google_analytics_automation_test`
ALTER TABLE `google_analytics_automation_test` 
ADD COLUMN Advertiser varchar(255) NOT NULL;

alter table `google_analytics_automation_test`
Add Advertiser AS
(CASE WHEN `Page` LIKE '%Aloxxi%' THEN Advertiser IS 'Aloxxi'
  WHEN `Page` LIKE '%Alfaparf%' THEN Advertiser IS 'AlfaParf'
 ELSE 'NA'
)

END AS 'Advertiser'
FROM `google_analytics_automation_test`;
```

I expect the code to search a column and return the advertiser name given I give it a list of all advertisers. Then add that new column to my data set called x.

if col.a contains apple then col.b is Apple
if col.a contains novalash then col.b is Nova Lash

EX:

```
 Col A                                                       Col B
 www.google.com/apple                                         Apple
 www.modernsalon.com/set-of-novalash-eyelash-extensions       Nova Lash
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the syntax for CASE, you've got a lot of unnecessary IS, AS and [columnname] in that one.

Correct syntax-

```
ALTER TABLE google_analytics_automation_test 
ADD COLUMN Advertiser varchar(255) AS (
    CASE WHEN Page LIKE '%Aloxxi%' THEN 'Aloxxi' 
    WHEN Page LIKE '%Alfaparf%' THEN 'AlfaParf' 
    ELSE 'NA' 
    END
);
```